# connect new Arch system to network

Tags: networking, arch-linux

During the installation of my new Arch system the Network was working fine, but I forgot to install a Network manager.

I tried setting a static IP address in my router and connect like this:

```
ip link set enp2s0 down
ip address flush dev enp2s0
ip address add 192.168.2.205/24 broadcast + dev enp2s0
ip link set enp2s0 up
```

following [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Network_configuration) official Arch guide

I recognized that when plugging in the cable I can ping the router, but when I wait a few seconds I can't.

Why can I still don't acmes the network?

Comment: Try `sudo dhcpcd enp2s0`.

Comment: dhcpcd is not preinstalled

Comment: Add default route

Comment: I just reinstalled my Arch again, but i think everyone would at least need dhcpcd in new Arch installations to avoid something like this^^